# Determine the value of $x$ given the slope of the tangent.

Tags: calculus

Determine $x$ where the slope of the tangent to $f(x) = 9x^2 + 15x + 25$ is equal to $8$.

I know that $f'(x) = m$, so will it be $f'(x) = 18x + 30 = 8$, or will it be $18x + 30 = -\frac{1}{8}$?

Comment: Why do you think it would be $-1/8$?

Comment: Don't you inverse it?

Comment: @myv Nope; then the equality wouldn't hold.

Comment: @Lovsovs, sorry i don't understand. Explain?

Comment: I'm currently writing an answer to your question, just a minute and it will be ready :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to answer this with a focus on teaching you how to think about what the equations *mean*.

Okay, so you have a function $f(x) = 9x^2 + 15x + 25$ and it's plotted here:

[image]

Now that function has a slope at any given point $x$, which is written as the function $f'(x)$, which I've also plotted:

[image]

Now, you're told that for some $x_0$ (I'm just calling it $x_0$ so we know it is a specific value of $x$), $f'(x_0)=8$. What does that *mean*? It means that, in the second graph, there is some $x=x_0$ that gives the value $8$ and that seems to be around $x \sim -0.5$ (I've just been reading off the graph).

Let's compare that to our algebraic work: 
 We differentiate, so now we have the general expression for $f'(x)=18x+15$ (note that I got something else than you; try checking your differentiation again). We know that when we plug in $x_0$, we get $8$, 
$$8=18x_0+15$$
so now we can solve for our $x_0$. Try it and see by how much my estimate was off!

Comment: THANKS!!! I understand much better now. The answer is -0,388. Just one more quick question...to get the y value, would you sub x into f (x) or f'(x)?

Comment: @myv The $y$-value is just the value on the $y-axis$ - so there's a $y$-value for both $f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)$. You'll have to understand from the context which of them is meant.

Comment: how to get the corresponding y value for x = -0, 388

Comment: @myv By $y$ is probably meant $f$, so plug it into that.

Comment: @myv Did you figure it out? Otherwise, just let me know.

Comment: Got it worked out. Thanks @Lovsovs

Comment: @MyV Glad I could help! If you liked my answer, you can upvote it and/or "accept" it (it is the tick under the voten up/down arrows next to my answer). Cheers.